# Calculated fields from queries in CTE are quite slow, how to optimize

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

I have a query with calculated fields which involves looking up a dataset within a CTE for each of them, but it's quite slow when I get to a couple of these fields.

Here's an idea:

```
;WITH TRNCTE AS
(
    SELECT TRN.PORT_N, TRN.TRADE_DATE, TRN.TRANS_TYPE, TRN.TRANS_SUB_CODE, TRN.SEC_TYPE, TRN.SETTLE_DATE 
    FROM TRNS_RPT TRN
    WHERE TRN.TRADEDT >= '2014-01-01' AND TRN.TRADEDT <= '2014-12-31'    
)

SELECT
    C.CLIENT_NAME,
    C.PORT_N,
    C.PHONE_NUMBER,
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TRNCTE WHERE PORT_N = C.PORT_N AND MONTH(SETTLE_DATE) = 12) THEN 'DECEMBER TRANSACTION'
        ELSE 'NOT DECEMBER TRANSACTION'
    END AS ALIAS1
FROM CLIENTS C
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TRNCTE WHERE PORT_N = C.PORT_N)
```

If I had many of these calculated fields, the query can take up to 10 minutes to execute. Gathering the data in the CTE takes about 15 seconds for around 1,000,000 records.

I don't really need JOINS since I'm not really using the data that a JOIN would do, I only want to check for the existence of records in TRNS_RPT with certains criterias and set alias fields to certain values whether I find such records or not.

Can you help me optimize this ? Thanks

Comment: what is you intent? Do you want to se your clients who have tranaction in december?

Comment: The CTE Will be "executed" once for each reference in the main query. The result is not cached and reused.

Comment: @PeterRing No. The intent is what it is as shown. If I have a transaction matching certain criterias for a certain client, certain flags (aliases) will have different values.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick what you can do in cases like this. You need to insert the result of the cte into a temp table. This way you will save the cost of the recalculation.
Plese give it a try.

```
;WITH TRNCTE AS
    (
        SELECT TRN.PORT_N, TRN.TRADE_DATE, TRN.TRANS_TYPE, TRN.TRANS_SUB_CODE, TRN.SEC_TYPE, TRN.SETTLE_DATE 
        FROM TRNS_RPT TRN
        WHERE TRN.TRADEDT >= '2014-01-01' AND TRN.TRADEDT <= '2014-12-31'    
    )
SELECT * INTO #temp
FROM TRNCTE

    SELECT
        C.CLIENT_NAME,
        C.PORT_N,
        C.PHONE_NUMBER,
        CASE
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #temp WHERE PORT_N = C.PORT_N AND MONTH(SETTLE_DATE) = 12) THEN 'DECEMBER TRANSACTION'
        ELSE 'NOT DECEMBER TRANSACTION'
    END AS ALIAS1
    FROM CLIENTS C
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #temp WHERE PORT_N = C.PORT_N)

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code I would probably do a `join` instead to avoid having to include `TRNCTE` twice in the query. It is not exactly the same if `TRNCTE.PORT_N` is not unique and you would get duplicate rows.

```
;WITH TRNCTE AS
(
    SELECT TRN.PORT_N, TRN.TRADE_DATE, TRN.TRANS_TYPE, TRN.TRANS_SUB_CODE, TRN.SEC_TYPE, TRN.SETTLE_DATE 
    FROM TRNS_RPT TRN
    WHERE TRN.TRADEDT >= '2014-01-01' AND TRN.TRADEDT <= '2014-12-31'    
)
SELECT
    C.CLIENT_NAME,
    C.PORT_N,
    C.PHONE_NUMBER,
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(TRNCTE.SETTLE_DATE) = 12) 
        THEN 'DECEMBER TRANSACTION'
        ELSE 'NOT DECEMBER TRANSACTION'
    END AS ALIAS1
FROM CLIENTS C
JOIN TRNCTE ON C.PORT_N = TRNCTE.PORT_N
```

Comment: This will sadly give a different result than the original. The original will show wich clients have transactions in december or not. Your soulution will show the clients multiple time if they have more than one transaction.

Comment: @PeterRing Yes, as stated in my answer.